# NULL master reference in detail implementing master-detail relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, master-detail

I'm implementing a master-detail relationship and I'm having troubles when persisting data. I defined the following classes to represent the relationship:

```
// MASTER
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "factura_cabecera")
public class FacturaEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Long numeroFactura;

    private LocalDateTime fechaEmision;
    private String nombreRazonSocial;
    private String codigoCliente;
    private BigDecimal montoTotal;
    private String usuario;
 
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "factura",
            cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE },
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<FacturaDetalleEntity> detalleList;
}

// DETAIL
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "factura_detalle")
public class FacturaDetalleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 500)
    private String descripcion;
    private BigDecimal cantidad;
    private Integer unidadMedida;
    private BigDecimal precioUnitario;
    private BigDecimal subTotal;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_factura", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private FacturaEntity factura;
}
```

I've also defined some classes to represent the request to the API and I'm using them this way to fill factura (master) and detalle (detail):

```
FacturaEntity factura = new FacturaEntity();
// filling factura properties
factura.setNumeroFactura(facturaElectronicaCompraVenta.getCabecera().getNumeroFactura());
...
// filling detalle properties
List<DetalleCompraVenta> detalleList = facturaElectronicaCompraVenta.getDetalle();
List<FacturaDetalleEntity> facturaDetalleList = new ArrayList<>();

for (DetalleCompraVenta detalle :detalleList) {
    facturaDetalleList.add(detalle);
}

factura.setDetalleList(facturaDetalleList);
// persist data
facturaRepository.save(factura);
```

But when querying database I get this result:
[image]
[image]

So, why is id_factura column filling up with NULL values? Thank you in advance for your colaboration.